# Is possible to merge records which are split by end of the month?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table which contains Names and Dates.

Which looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuWSD.png]

And I need it to looks like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXXYL.png]

Is it possible? I coun't find way how to do it.

Comment: Please don't post image of data. Take the time to either supplied your data as tabular formatted `text` or as DDL and DML statements. Images don't help us help you, as we can't use the data contained in your images without transcribing it; which many users won't do.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a combination of lag difference and running sum

```
WITH CTE1
AS
(
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(TODATE) OVER (ORDER BY TODATE),FROMDATE) =1  THEN NULL ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FROMDATE) END AS COL1  --in case the last ToDate and current FromDate  are consecutive, use a NULL mark
,* 
FROM Table
)
,CTE2 AS
(
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(COL1,0)) OVER (ORDER BY FROMDATE) AS RUNNINGSUM  ----sum up consecutive rows adding 0 in case of a NULL value 
,* FROM CTE1
)
SELECT NAME,MIN(FROMDATE) AS FROMDATE,MAX(TODATE) AS TODATE FROM CTE2
GROUP BY RUNNINGSUM,NAME
```